# Drawing lines on scaled canvas in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF control which shows an image that the user can scale, flip and rotate. Along with that overlaid is a canvas where the user can draw lines. The lines are drawn low-level using DrawingContext. I use a RenderTransformer on the canvas to keep the image and canvas in sync.

I now have a case where an image is scaled differently in x- and y- direction. This obviously leads to the effect that the lines are "skewed", ie. if the image is scaled in x-direction, vertical lines are thicker than horizontal lines.

[image]

Any idea how to correct this? DrawingContext.PushTransform with a ScaleTransform would work for the thickness, but it obviously changes the coordinates.

Comment: Draw LineGeometry or PathGeometry and set its Transform property.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would go about solving this problem is as follows:

I would create the transform, and apply it to the image, but I would not apply it to the canvas.

Then, when drawing each line on the canvas, I would use `Transform.Transform(Point)` to manually map each point of the line to the right location of the canvas. That would have the effect of not messing with the pen.